# Does being banned/deported from one country prevent getting a visa in another?

Tags: visas, europe, visa-refusals, netherlands, deportation

Does being deported and banned from the both UAE and Qatar for drug use impede me from being granted a European visa? I plan to apply to the Netherlands for a student visa.

Comment: No, not at all. Buggery, for example, is the prime illustration.  Do you want to clarify your question?

Comment: `deported and banned` The willn't refuse you, but will use a humongously big magnifying glass to look at your application in much detail.

Answer (score 4):

It will definitely [slow the movement, progress, or action of](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impede) processing your visa application relative to other applications in otherwise identical circumstances since for others it is one less thing for the people doing the processing to check.

It does not necessarily *prevent* the granting of a visa.

Comment: What if i don't tell them about it? Would they still find out? There's nothing on my passport about it. Just cancelled visas. I have travelled to Spain a couple of months before I got deported. thanks.